# New Relic - Custom attributes in .NET IIS

Tags: newrelic, apm

I am using NewRelic to monitor our performance of IIS and MSSQL queries. However, right now the data is too generic and I want to pin down and find slow running queries or requests for each user.

Is there a possibility to add a User Id attribute that I can use to filter my data in the New Relic dashboard later on? This should probably be added in the Begin_Request in Global.asax or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Custom attributes can be added quite easily using the [AddCustomAttribute API](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/agents/net-agent/net-agent-api/itransaction/#addcustomattribute)  and adding them on something like Begin_Request

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).